# Convert c# to vb.net 'RaiseEvent' statement to raise an event to use Gzip

Tags: events, gzip, raise, raiseevent

I have convert class from c# to vb.net .. My point that I want to compress asp.net page to reduce the page size ,, Problem is after i convert to vb.net ,i have this error

> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource
> required to service this request. Please review the following specific
> error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: BC32022: 'Public Event
> PostRequestHandlerExecute(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)' is
> an event, and cannot be called directly. Use a 'RaiseEvent' statement
> to raise an event.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 178:
>
> Line 179:    Private Sub Init(context As HttpApplication) Implements IHttpModule.Init
>
> Line 180: context.PostRequestHandlerExecute += New EventHandler(context_BeginRequest)
>
> Line 181:    End Sub
>
> Line 182:

im trying to implement Gzip for asp.net ...
thanks in advance ....

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[`AddHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka.aspx) is the VB.NET equivalent to C#’s `+=` when used on events.

```vb
AddHandler context.PostRequestHandlerExecute, AddressOf context_BeginRequest
```

Comment: Bingo. I don't know why but the [Telerik converter](http://converter.telerik.com/) messes this up and I don't use AddressOf enough to keep remembering this.

Answer (score 8):

You need to use the `AddHandler` statement, not `+=`.  that is `c#` syntax.

```
AddHandler context.PostRequstHandlerExecute, New EventHandler(AddressOf context_BeginRequest)
```